# OSX localhost mail in mail.app?

Tags: macos, terminal, localhost, apple-mail

Every time I start a Terminal I see that I have unread mail. I know that I can access them via the mail command but I'm not comfortable in using that command.

Is there any way to read the local mail via the mail.app?

And also is the address to send local mail myusername@mycomputername.local?